# Neo4j CSV import datatype error

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am trying to import genealogy data into Neo4j using a CSV file. The dates are strings such as 2012 or 19860105). However, when importing, Neo4j interprets them as LongValue, creating an error.

My import statement is either

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Neo4jPersonNodes1.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
CREATE (:Person{RN: toInteger(line[0]),fullname: line[1],surname: line[2],name: line[3],sex: line[4],union_id: toInteger(line[5]),mn: line[6],BD: line[7],BDGed: line[8],DD: line[9],DDGed: line[10],bp_id: toInteger(line[11]),dp_id: toInteger(line[12]),BP: line[13],DP: line[14],kit: line[15]})
```

or, adding the toString() function

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Neo4jPersonNodes1.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
CREATE (:Person{RN: toInteger(line[0]),fullname: toString(line[1]),surname: toString(line[2]),name: toString(line[3]),sex: toString(line[4]),union_id: toInteger(line[5]),mn: toString(line[6]),BD: toString(line[7]),BDGed: toString(line[8]),DD: toString(line[9]),DDGed: toString(line[10]),bp_id: toInteger(line[11]),dp_id: toInteger(line[12]),BP: toString(line[13]),DP: toString(line[14]),kit: toString(line[15])})
```

A sample of the CSV is

```
"RN"|"fullname"|"surname"|"name"|"sex"|"union_id"|"mn"|"BD"|"BDGed"|"DD"|"DDGed"|"bp_id"|"dp_id"|"BP"|"DP"|"kit"
"5"|"Ale Harmens Slump"|"Slump"|"Ale Harmens"|"M"|"313"|"3"|"18891223"|"23 Dec 1889"|"19890111"|"11 Jan 1989"|"23"|"4552"|"Echten, Friesland, Neth."|"Sebastopol, California"|""
```

the error message is:

> Neo4j.Driver.V1.ClientException: 'Error when pulling unconsumed
>   session.run records into memory in session: Expected Long(7) to be a
>   org.neo4j.values.storable.TextValue, but it was a
>   org.neo4j.values.storable.LongValue'

I'm not sure why Neo4j does not treat the  numeric string as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your CSV file has a header row (and specified `WITH HEADERS`), your Cypher code must treat `line` as a map (whose property names match all your header names) instead of as an array.

For example, instead of `line[0]`, you must use `line.RN`. If you fix all the uses of `line` accordingly, you should no longer get such errors.